# Pandas + Django + mod_wsgi + virtualenv

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, virtualenv, pandas

Pandas is producing **'module' object has no attribute 'core'** when being imported under `django` and `mod_wsgi` inside a virtual environment.  It works fine running under the `django` development server inside the virtual environment.

Other modules e.g.: numpy have no problems so I assume this means the virtual environment is set up correctly with `mod_wsgi`.  Any advice would be appreciated.

#### staging.wsgi

```
import os
import sys
import site

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
site_packages = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'env/openportfolio/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
site.addsitedir(os.path.abspath(site_packages))
sys.path.insert(0, PROJECT_ROOT)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'openportfolio.settings_staging'

import pandas #triggers error
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

#### Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/web/django/www/staging/openportfolio/apache/staging.wsgi", line 22, in <module>
    import pandas
  File "/usr/local/web/django/www/staging/env/openportfolio/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import *
  File "/usr/local/web/django/www/staging/env/openportfolio/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/api.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pandas.core.datetools as datetools
  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'core'
```

#### Python Path

```
['/usr/local/web/django/www/staging/openportfolio',
 '/usr/local/web/django/www/staging',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.0.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/web/django/www/staging/env/openportfolio/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/web/django/www/staging/env/openportfolio/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.0.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/web/django/www/staging/env/openportfolio/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.1.0-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/web/django/www/staging/env/openportfolio/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

Comment: Are you sure you have all the dependencies and have built the C extensions? I usually see errors like that when something that pandas depends on failed to import

Comment: It imports fine and runs when not using mod_wsgi so that somehow seems to be the issue. I installed via pip.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out this was a Python path order issue. By running sys.path.reverse() in my wsgi config file, the code now runs.

Due to the order of Python path, the built in OS X numpy library must have been imported first over the virtual environment one causing the issue.

**'RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 6 but this version of numpy is 4'** was the error line I missed in my original post which could have helped debug the answer.